# Hive Java UDF on Avro tables

Tags: java, hadoop, hive, user-defined-functions, avro

Im familiar with Hive UDF using Java and run them on external tables that are based on text files, I tried to run the same UDF against table that is based on Avro Snappy files, but it just prints `OK` with no result and no Error.
Im using Eclipse to develop it and put the main class in the run configuration as `org.apache.hadoop.io.ArrayFile` and it looks like :

```
public class debugger extends UDF{
    public Text evaluate(Text input) throws HiveException{  
        return (new Text("dummy"));
    }
}
```

Comment: UDF should not care if the file is avro or text, the SerDe does, so the problem must be somewhere else, most likely, you're querying an empty avro file. What happens if you do

    select count(1) from my_avro_table

Comment: @RobertoCongiu Thank you, this is exactly what i want as answer, i have a problem whith my table.